# Getting TXT file to Excel

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code to get a text file to an Excel workbook.

```
    Dim XlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim XlWbk As Excel.Workbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim SheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim XlWkst As Excel.Worksheet = FindSheet(XlWbk, SheetName)
    Dim XlRng As Excel.Range = Nothing

    If XlWkst Is Nothing Then
        XlWkst = DirectCast(XlWbk.Sheets.Add(After:=XlWbk.Sheets(XlWbk.Sheets.Count), _
        Count:=1, Type:=Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet), Excel.Worksheet)
    End If

    Dim Lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\TEMP\FlowgateNNL_Mar2011_base.txt")
    Dim RC(Lines.Length - 1)() As String
    For I As Integer = 0 To Lines.Length - 1
        RC(I) = Lines(I).Split(CChar(vbTab))
    Next

    XlRng = XlWkst.Range("a1")
    XlRng.Value = RC

    XlApp.Visible = True
```

This method seems to be the fastest way to read and parse a CSV file for dumping to Excel on my computer. it is choking on `XlRng.Value = RC`. Excel doesn't seem to like RC.

Any ideas for getting Excel to accept the data?

Comment: What is the error?  Also, is the range you are specifying a single cell and you're feeding it an array of string arrays?

Comment: "Specified array was not the expected type." No, the range is actually "a1:" & CellOffsetAddress but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the value of a cell to an array that contains an entire CSV? I'm guessing this throws a type error.
This is probably more along the lines of what you want.

```
    Dim XlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim XlWbk As Excel.Workbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim SheetName As String = "Sheet1"
    Dim XlWkst As Excel.Worksheet = FindSheet(XlWbk, SheetName)
    Dim XlRng As Excel.Range = Nothing

    If XlWkst Is Nothing Then
        XlWkst = DirectCast(XlWbk.Sheets.Add(After:=XlWbk.Sheets(XlWbk.Sheets.Count), _
        Count:=1, Type:=Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet), Excel.Worksheet)
    End If

    Dim Lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\TEMP\FlowgateNNL_Mar2011_base.txt")

    For I As Integer = 0 To Lines.Length - 1
        XlRng = XlWkst.Range("a1").Offset(I, 0)
        Dim RC() As String = Lines(I).Split(CChar(vbTab))
        For J As Integer = 0 To RC.Length - 1
            XlRng = XlRng.Offset(0, J)
            XlRng.Value = RC(J)
        Next
    Next

    XlApp.Visible = True
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I was hoping to find something that could dump the array in one pass rather than dumping segments of the array. The txt file is 160680 rows X 16 columns wide so your method is taking quite a while. I know how to do this if it is rectangular array, but the jagged array is throwing me off.

Comment: yah, can't think of anything to help you there. Either way moving that much data into excel is gonna take a while, somehow using only one call probably wouldn't change a whole lot... but who knows

Answer (score 1):

Did you try simply opening the CSV file directly as in:

```
Dim XlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
Dim XlWbk As Excel.Workbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\TEMP\FlowgateNNL_Mar2011_base.txt")
XlApp.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid CSV file do yourself a favor and use a specialised CSV datareader which can handle all the weird problems of CSVs (quotes etc.)
Personally, I like **http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/** very much - it is simple to use and fast.

Then just dump the interop part and use the **EPPLUS** Library to write the data to an excel file - it is magnitudes faster and mind boggingly simple.
Your workflow would look like this: 
Use KBCSV to load the data to a datatable. 
Use EPPLUS's method "LoadFromDataTable" to generate a new excel file and save it.
Done!